# Drools with SOAP web service in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, drools

In eclipse, I am developing a soap based web service for which I decided to make use of Drools for writing business logic. 
This is what I did to integrate drools to eclipse:
- Installed the drools plugin in eclipse using "Install new software" option.
- Copied all the drools jar files into "Referenced Libraries" folder.
- Continued working with my previously created dynamic web project with the newly added drools jar files.

At one stage of my thread (launched using threadpool executor's submit method) where I am building the knowledge base, I have kieServices initialization as shown below:

```
kieServices ks = kieServices.Factory.get();
```

But the application crashes at this point. When I tried to debug in eclipse, the application reaches this initialization point and when I step into it as part of debugging, it takes me to one of the catch blocks of java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.class.

So, there is some exception being thrown by this factory which I could not catch even using base Exception class. It is neither being caught nor I can see any stack trace in any of the tomcat logs.

```
    try {
        // load up the knowledge base
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
        ...
        ...
         }
    catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: this kieServices factory call works just fine if I use the same drools jar in a separate Drools project (not dynamic web project) in eclipse.

Comment: "takes me to one of the catch blocks of java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.class", did you inspected the exception object at that point? Did you tried enabling TRACE logging level on that Drools package?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I figured out the issue, it was throwing NoClassDefFoundError of type Throwable which I was not catching in my application.  Got rid of this exception by copying required jars for KieServices in runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue myself.
There was an exception being thrown of type Throwable for which the catch block was missing from the code. The exception thrown was NoClassDefFoundError.
Added the catch block and got rid of exception by copying missing jars in runtime environment.